# How to pass Query String Parameter name with a dot in RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a query string parameter from one controller to another through RedirectToAction method.

However, my parameter name is something like "abc.Key" but I am not being able specify such a value to RedirectToaction as it gives me error.

My RedirectToAction currently looks like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Pending", "SimpleController", 
    new { area = "Area1", Activities.ActivityGroupKey=qstring });
```

I searched a lot to figure out how it can be done but to no fruits.

Comment: What error does it give you? There is [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429281/error-with-dot-character-in-url) right next to yours.

Comment: The question you are referring to is regarding error because of dot in URL. My question is about how I can write the parameter name with a dot in RedirectToAction method.

Comment: My bad. And how does your other method looks like, what does it get as input parameter?

Comment: RedirectToAction is an ASP.NET MVC method, which is used to redirect to a controller/action. Refer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using `RouteValueDictionary` to solve my problem

This is How I did it:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Pending", "SimpleController", new RouteValueDictionary{
    { "area","Area1" },
    { "Activities.ActivityGroupKey",qstring}
    } );
```